# 2008 Server R2 + Classic View Control Panel?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

Please say they didn't get rid of Classic View for the Control Panel.  Does anyone know how I can change to Classic View in R2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with this too recently. Leave it for this genius to figure how to screw with a bad menu program.

Fortunately there is a solution, http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/

Tested on Windows 7 and Windows 2008 64 bits on both without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see they got rid of all the classic views in R2.

Comment: BOO!! HISS!! And here I was looking forward to my first meeting with R2.

Comment: Don't be afraid of change

Answer (score 0):

Try http://csmenu.com/ Does the job for me.

Comment: Looks like this is for the start menu, not the control panel... but I haven't downloaded it, so I might be wrong.  Verify, please?